# Is there a web-page blocks the find_element function to work? WTO official repository

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get the Panel Report of WTO automatically using selenium package in python.

https://docs.wto.org/dol2fe/Pages/FE_Search/FE_S_S006.aspx?Query=(@Symbol=%20wt/ds2/*)&Language=ENGLISH&Context=FomerScriptedSearch&languageUIChanged=true#

while I was working with above page, I've got into error - that no element is not gettable.

In other words, specially I'd like to inspect "Panel Report Tab" and click it, like using the following code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentLeft_Tabs_tab001_wpcTypesTreeView_trvTypes"]/ul/li[8]/div/span[2]')
```

but keep failing with an error message :

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
>   element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ctl00_TopLevelNavigationWUC_lnkRecentDocuments"]"}
>   (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.34.522932
>   (4140ab217e1ca1bec0c4b4d1b148f3361eb3a03e),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.2
>   x86_64)

So I had tried this with another xpath, but keep returning same error.

How could I get the element for clicking to get into the panel-report page?

EDIT: I am using Python but one user referred this question to JAVA cases and marked it as a duplication.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException" when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome)

Comment: try to add wait before this event

Comment: @DebanjanB I had checked the referred link, but there's no webdriverwait method in my python and its package selenium. Any hint to proceed?

Comment: @AnkurSingh is there a function wait in webdriver?

Comment: @DebanjanB I don' have a time to learn JAVA and my post explicitly shows this is about python. But you just turns it into Duplication. why?

Comment: from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait use this class

Comment: refer this link http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:-

```
 element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ctl00_ContentLeft_Tabs_tab001_wpcTypesTreeView_trvTypes']/ul/li[8]/div/span[2]"))
    )
```

Comment: while I didn't use webdriver wait, if I had already waited more than an hour, still do I need to use wait?

Comment: yeah we need to wait for webelement to apper in DOM after that only we are able to interact with it